# Custom UIView How to Respond to Constraint-based frame changes

Tags: ios, ios7, nslayoutconstraint

I have a container UIView that has constraints that will cause it to change height to match either an old 3.5" iPhone or a new 4" iPhone. Inside that container UIView, I have several copies of a custom UIView, let's call it `DynamicButton`. `DynamicButton` has three subviews which are laid out using their frames (no constraints) and whenever `[DynamicButton -setFrame]` is called, the frames of the three subviews are re-computed

My constraints are set up so that my `DynamicButton` views will fill the entire container view with equal heights.

In `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear` the height of my containerView is the height it is in the storyboard (regardless of the device). My `DynamicButton`s are `58` pixels tall.

In `viewDidAppear`, the constraints have finally taken effect and the containerView height gets reduced to the right value when being displayed on an old 3.5" iPhone, and my `DynamicButton`s are `47` pixels tall.

However, my `DynamicButton` class never receives a `setFrame` message when it changes size.

What method do I need to override to intercept that size change so I can reconfigure the frames on my subviews?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override `layoutSubviews` in `DynamicButton` and set your subviews' frames there.

From the documentation for `layoutSubviews`:

> [...] Subclasses can override this method as needed to perform more precise layout of their subviews. You should override this method only if the autoresizing and constraint-based behaviors of the subviews do not offer the behavior you want. You can use your implementation to set the frame rectangles of your subviews directly. [...]

Comment: Weird, I tried that before too and it wasn't getting called... gah, I must have missed something or did it wrong the first time because that is working now. Thanks. Also, it's pronounced BeardfaCEY.

Comment: @KennyWyland Haha, finally someone gets my name. Yeah no prob! Weird that it wasn't working the first time.